# What is the exact role of "inline" after the src here?

Tags: javascript, html

Usually, a script tag would look something like

```
<script src="/scripts/color.js"></script>
```

But I came across the one below

```
<script src="/scripts/color.js" inline></script>
```

So, what purpose is "inline" supposed to serve now?

Answer (score 0):

There is no [attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#attributes-3) named `inline` anywhere in HTML.

It is most likely either an error or something that should be represented by a [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Answer (score 0):

The `inline` attribute is not a valid attribute for the `<script>` tag.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script for the list of valid attributes.

Maybe the person who wrote this code thought about "inline script", which usually means writing the code directly in the HTML:

```html
<script>
  // javascript goes here
</script>
```

Comment: Or maybe it's some framework-specific attribute